# Error on implementing interface

Tags: c#

This will likely (hopefully?) be an "amateur hour" type question. :)

I'm new to interfaces, etc. and doing things correctly, but I have an MVC 3 project that references a C# library project.

In the C# library project, I have the following code:

```
    public interface IRepositoryAddable<T>
    {
        void Add(T entity);
    }
```

I repeat this sort of code for other types of repository so that I can make things easier and standard across all my repositories.

For example, I have a repository for anything of type "ISkill":

```
public interface ISkillRepository : IRepositoryAddable<ISkill>, IRepositoryDeleteable<ISkill>, IRepositoryDeleteableByID<ISkill, int>, IRepositoryGettableByID<ISkill, int>, IRepositoryListable<ISkill>, IRepositorySavable<ISkill>
{ }
```

Then, in my actual repository, I have:

```
    public class SkillRepository : ISkillRepository
    {
        public void Add(Skill skillToAdd)
        {
            return;
        }
}
```

As far as I'm aware, this should suffice to implement the ISkillRepositoryListable interface. However, I receive the following error:

> Error 5   'DakotaSkills.MVC.Models.Repository.SkillRepository'
>   does not implement interface member
>   'DakotaSkills.Lib.Interfaces.Repository.IRepositoryAddable.Add(DakotaSkills.Lib.Interfaces.ISkill)'   C:\Users\Sean\Projects\Web\DakotaSkills\src\DakotaSkills.MVC\Models\Repository\SkillRepository.cs   11  18  DakotaSkills.MVC

Other interface methods for the repository have shown as being implemented fine and I'm not quite sure what I'm doing wrong. For the record, my "Skill" type implements "ISkill" and I receive no error on its implementation.

Help?

Thanks!

Comment: Go to the `SkillRepository` class file, right click the `ISkillRepository`
 interface name and click on `"Implement Interface"` from the context menu. Visual Studio will create all the correct methods signature you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Add would not accept some other class that also implemented ISkill. You need to take an ISkill, not just a Skill. That also suggests that your implementation of Add, should it ever do anything, should do so through ISkill only and not by calling other Skill methods you may know about.

Comment: public class SkillRepository : ISkillRepository
    {
        public void Add(ISkill skillToAdd)
        {
            return;
        }
    }

Comment: Ahh, I see, Kaite. Thank you for the complete explanation! Makes much more sense when I hear it that way.

Answer (score 2):

You've defined the interface as having:

```
void Add(ISkill skillToAdd)
```

but, you're implementing

```
void Add(Skill skillToAdd)
```

which means they don't match. If I have a different `ISkill` implementation, I can't use your `SkillRepository`.

You either need to make `SkillRepository` work with *any* `ISkill`, or change your `ISkillRepoistory` interface to use a concrete `Skill` as its type parameters.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks! However, if I'm using Skill, which is derived from ISkill, shouldn't it accept that since it knows that Skill is derived from ISkill? I think that's where I'm confused. I thought since Skill implemented ISkill, you could use it in the place of an ISkill just fine.

Comment: @goober - You can pass a Skill to anything that is expecting an ISkill, just as you can pass an integer like 3 to a function that takes a float. But writing a function that takes an integer doesn't satisfy the requirement to write a function that takes a float. All Skills are ISkills - it's possible that some completely different class besides Skill could implement ISkill, so not all ISkills are Skills. You know you wouldn't, but the compiler doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
public class SkillRepository : ISkillRepository
{
    public void Add(ISkill skillToAdd)
    {
        return;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Skill is a more specific type than ISkill, so I think you need to change your implementation of Add to accept ISkill, rather than Skill:

```
    public void Add(ISkill skillToAdd)
    {
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Hi KOTJMF, thanks for the tip -- however, I have a question on this from a theory perspective -- please see my comment on Mark's answer.

Answer (score -1):

I'd need to see your call site, i.e. the calling code

However this sounds too complicated. Read this and have a think http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2011/03/24/the-wages-of-sin-hit-that-database-one-more-timehellip.aspx

Comment: Hi Adam, thanks for the input but I've weighed the pros & cons of different repository implementations and this is more of a technical question, not a strategy question. Thanks though!

Comment: @jfar Everyone makes mistakes or needs a little help at some point, what was the purpose of your comment other than to troll?

Comment: It may be a technical question but as far as I can see this feels an order of magnitude too complicated. I cannot imagine a circumstance where you need six interfaces on a repository.I'm also not quite sure how querying architecture gets down voted, hey ho.

Comment: @KOTJMF - A good friend doesn't let you jump off a bridge.  Sorry you took my comment the wrong way.

Comment: Hi all, the short answer is that this was a thought experiment, not a real world implementation is what I meant. Abstracting repositories doesn't make sense in the real world (particularly if using EF as I am), and I understand this. However, this question did help me get a better grip on some technical principles, so I don't consider it a loss. I fixed my abstractions and refactored them away; a net win for all involved.

Comment: Also, some clarifications: @jfar, I also found your comment a little trolling in that it made negative assumptions about my skillset based on my question; a more constructive, insightful response (as I know you're capable of) would have been appreciated. The down vote was my fault; it was actually an accident that I didn't see. @adam, if you edit your comment, I'd be happy to remove it. Thanks!